# I can see some packages in the repo but I couldn't able to use `apt show` or `apt install` on that packages

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Some packages like `libprelude` are marked as dependencies to some packages (Depends field in the control file), but I'm unable to read the control file using `apt show`. In fact I'm unable to use `apt install` against this package. But I'm able to download these packages using `apt source`. Any idea what's happening here?

package available in focal: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libprelude

I'm using focal container.

my apt [sources.list](https://pastebin.com/AcMFJ5gm)

Comment: `source` packages (the `deb-src` lines in your sources) are not the same as compiled binary packages. Source packages are NOT ready-to-run, and cannot be so installed by apt. Folks who do not quite grok the difference between source packages and binary packages should avoid source packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link shows it is the source package for `libprelude` which means that it is not a compiled version so `apt show` won't work on it and neither will `apt install`.  `apt` can only download it when you run `apt source libprelude`.  However, `apt show` and `apt install` will work on all the other binaries listed below it on that page that are compiled from that source code, i.e. `apt show libprelude28`.